# Hibernate Lazy - impact of using no-proxy fetching mode?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate 4.2 and we have encountered somes issues with `@OneToOne` relation and `@Lob` in lazy mode. 
This is a known issue, hibernate will fecth data in eager mode instead of lazy : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one

In order to solve it, I have tried to use bytecode instrumentation. Now, my `@OneToOne` relation does not use proxy : `@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`.

It works fine ! But there is something that I don't understand... Why hibernate use by default a proxy fetching mode if there is some issue that can be resolve by using the bytecode instrumentation (no proxy mode)?

Why this mode is not used by default ?
What are the consequence / inconveniance of using this no proxy-mode ?

I documented me about the differences between proxy and no-proxy mode, but I don't find the advantages / disadvantages of each mode.

Because it seems that even if I use the bytecode instrumentation, it will only be used for relation that as marked as `NO_PROXY`, isn't it ?

Thanks for your helps.